# File does not exsist exception when reading from hdfs Hadoop1.0.3

Tags: hadoop

I have around 100 images stored in my hdfs  inside input/testingImagesInput as you can see below.

```
hduser@livingstream:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls input
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-06-03 12:07 /user/hduser/input/testingImagesInput
```

I am trying to read those images and write them into a sequence file using the following code:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://localhost:54310");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
FSDataInputStream  in = null;
BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable();
Text key = new Text();
Path inpath = new Path(fs.getWorkingDirectory(),"input/testingImagesInput");
Path seq_path = new Path("seq_path");
```

After setting up the paths and configs , sequencefilewriter will write to seq_path after reading from inpath

```
SequenceFile.Writer writer = null;
try {
    System.out.println("reading from :"+inpath);
    in =  fs.open(inpath);
    byte bufffer[] = new  byte[in.available()];
    in.read(bufffer);
               writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs,conf,seq_path,key.getClass(),value.getClass());
writer.append(new Text(inpath.getName()), new BytesWritable(bufffer));
        }catch (Exception e) {
                               TODO// handle e
        }
```

However , when executing the line

in =  fs.open(inpath);

it throws me the following error :

```
reading from :hdfs://localhost:54310/input/testingImagesInput // form sysout.
Exception MESSAGES = File does not exist: /input/testingImagesInput
```

I am not sure whats happening wrong ! can any one point me to the right direction please.

**UPDATE**

So I am giving the directory path i.e  **hdfs:localhost:54310/user/hduser/input/testingImagesInput** and not specifying any name of the image, when I added the name of image its able to read it.

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that the path it's giving you is `/input/testingImagesInput`, and not `input/testingImagesInput` or `/user/hduser/input/testingImagesInput`, which would indicate it's giving you the absolute path, which means it probably thinks the working directory is `/`; unless it's just giving you the path relative to the root of the server. Have you tried printing out the working directory directly to check?

Comment: @ParthianShot fs.getworkingDirectory() prints : hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser